# Is ASSERT redundant?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, assert

```
ASSERT(pointer);
pointer->x;
```

In this code, the ASSERT seems to be redundant. If the pointer is NULL, pointer->x will fail anyway. Is my argument correct?

Comment: I prefer:
ASSERT(NULL != pointer && "Button initialization failed");

Comment: In debug it helps. In release ASSERT does nothing anyway. So think of it as addtional documentation about the pre conditions of the function.

Comment: Note that it should be `assert`, not `ASSERT`. In C89, the argument to `assert` should be of type `int`, so you should probably write `assert(pointer != NULL)`. `assert(pointer)` is OK in C99 though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The important (if not main) purpose of assertions is to *document* the invariants that are supposed to hold at certain point in the code. The fact that `assert` can also abort the program if the invariant is broken is just icing on the cake, albeit a very useful one. I'd say that in a typical program 90% of assertions are assertions that rather obviously can't fail and never will fail. In other words, `assert` is to a large degree a kind of formalized comment language. Formalized in a sense that these "comments" are written in the same language the rest of the code is written in (C/C++), as opposed to plain English.

In your code sample the assertion is there to tell you that the pointer is not supposed to be null here. That's why it is there. In that sense this `assert` is not redundant.

As far as the execution flow is concerned, `assert` is always redundant, which is why assertions are typically not compiled in the release version of the code. There's nothing to prevent you from keeping the assertions in release code as well, but normally it is done by introducing a special kind of "release assertion". In any case, making the main functionality of the code depend in the actions taken by an assertion is not a good programming practice. Assertions are supposed to be redundant, as far as the main functionality of the code is concerned.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, but `pointer->x` will (I presume) fail in an uncontrolled way, whereas the `assert` will fail and tell you exactly where.

In some sense, `assert` is *always* redundant, of course.

Comment: except in release build. It'll just crash.

Comment: Basically, asserts are typically used to allow developer-specific handling for debugging exceptional cases, that can then be easily compiled out for production builds.

Comment: Actually, `pointer->x` _may_ crash at runtime. It _may_ work fine though. I've worked in a number of environments that only faulted on large memory addresses and not small addresses. Never assume that it will fail.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not redundant. The assertion will stop execution before anything bad happens. On the other hand, if you dereference an invalid pointer you might cause real corruption, or at the very least an uncontrolled segfault rather than a controlled abortion.

Answer (score 1):

`ASSERT` is not part of the C standard, so could be anything

```
 #define ASSERT(x) do { \
     x = malloc ( sizeof *x ); \
     memset ( x, 0, sizeof *x );\
     } while ( 0 )
```

`assert` is a different matter.

Some people have an `ASSERT` macro which calls the debugger, some have one which does other debugging or logging, and use the stringification feature of the pre-processor.

You really have to say what the macro does for anyone to know whether it is important.

Comment: I'm sure the assert he refers to is in the same style as `assert`.

Comment: Even if he did mean `assert`, there is a line between pedantry and attention to detail. You simply cannot survive in a C or C++ environment without meticulous attention to detail, so I find this sort of correction to be useful, even if the intent of the OP is obvous in this particular case

Comment: It would have made a much better comment.

Comment: @dreamlax nothing, but I'm used to writing the first few fields and zeroing out the rest, so got in the habit

Answer (score 0):

On some cases assert can be used for debugging
http://simonwillison.net/2008/May/22/debugging/

Answer (score 0):

`ASSERT` can also be used to check for invalid or illogical conditions that may not cause a crash.  Here's a horribly contrived example:

```
void cpu_hog(int duration)
{
    int start_time = (int) time(NULL);
    int end_time   = start_time + duration;

    ASSERT(end_time > start_time);  /* If this fails, "int" is too small. */

    while ((int) time(NULL) < end_time)
        ;
}
```

One small note:  most proponents of `ASSERT` recommend you use it only to validate the assumptions you make as you write the code (for example, a pointer is non-NULL, or a condition cannot occur).  It's generally considered a *bad* idea to use `ASSERT` to trap user-related errors or exceptions that are expected to occur (for example, disk full) because (1) `ASSERT` exists only in a debug build, and (2) even if you promote your debug code to production, it will crash instead of handling the condition gracefully.

Answer (score -1):

The ASSERT is not to fail. It is here to stop a debugger on a breakpoint. This will not affect a release build.

Comment: This is not ultimately true: assert may be defined in debug build only, which is common case. But some asserts are also defined in release build! Some projects define a DEBUG_ASSERT() and a plain ASSERT() which is enabled in release builds.